# String Comparison from text file does not return anything

Tags: string, comparison, buffer

i am a beginner in Java, i was trying to read a text from a text file and compare it to Strings i created within my class, for some reason it does not output anything on the console and i can't help but wonder why. Here's my simple code

```
package BinaryServer;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class DriverState {

    public static void main (String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        String DriverState="";
        String Not="Not Drowsy";
        String Yes="Drowsy";

         try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Mohamed Ayman/Desktop/State.txt"))) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
                DriverState = sb.toString();
            }

        if (DriverState.equals(Not)){

            System.out.println("User is not drowsy");
        }
        else if (DriverState.equals(Yes)){

            System.out.println("User is drowsy");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, i removed the line

sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

and then it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you're adding line breaks to `DriverState` that are not present in `Yes` or `No`, so both comparisons will always return false.

On a side note: the Java naming convention for variables, fields and methods is [lower camel case](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LowerCamelCase), so `driverState` instead of `DriverState`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, i removed the line

sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

and then it worked perfectly